# Selection from layer panel in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, selections

Lets say I have selected a bunch of objects in the layer panel (as shown in the following capture), is there a way to select the corresponding path without having to click on each circle individually holding the command key?

[image: layer panel]

Comment: Well you can click on the layer and it selects everything in that layer.

Comment: No. You have to click the circles. Layer/Object highlighting is in *no way* related to object selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question- no, there is not a way to highlight items in the layers panel and then turn them into a selection

This has been a frustration for me also- often I want to select several items from the layers panel- having to click each circle (often called the meatball) can be tedious

your question prompted me to investigate further and I discovered  a helpful technique

If you hold the option (alt) key you can click in the layers panel anywhere from the thumbnail to the "meatball" and it will select that object. If you add the shift key you can add to the selection but you still have to click each item separately. This is a bit faster than having to click on each "meatball".

If you click on several non sequential objects it does a strange thing of highlighting all the layer objects that are between the 2 selected objects, but it does not select them.

I have always wanted the ability to select objects from the layers panel just as you can with the lock or show (eyeball) icons- by clicking and dragging up or down- I am not sure why this is not available

[image: added gif]